# "Always refresh from server" in Firefox

Tags: firefox

[image]

The above highlighted feature is available in IE developer tools.  Is there such a feature available in Firefox browser or Firebug?

With such feature, we don't have to bother to clean the cache for any code changes we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions for cache bypass in all (or most) browsers can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache).

Comment: thanks mkumpan.  I found the keyboard shortcut ctrl + shift + r from the above link.  This solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> whenever you want to refresh the page?